# What is performing Transparent Content Negotiation in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache-config

I inherited a fairly complex Java web application that exhibits a mysterious behaviour and I need to know what causes it.

The application requests a file `file.css`. If `file.css` exists it is returned. If `file.css` does not exist, but `file.css.gz` does exist, the gzipped file is returned, with the following unusual headers:

```
Content-Location: file.css.gz
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
TCN: choice
Vary: negotiate
```

The presence of the [TCN header](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2295.txt) means that a request was transparently negotiated, most likely by an Apache RewriteRule, but I can't find where the rule is defined. I've located and searched every Apache config file on the server (multiple files are referenced with `Include`) and commented-out every mention of "gzip" or ".gz". Across all config files there is only a single RewriteRule and it's for SSL. After restarting Apache I still can't disable the behaviour.

Is this the default behaviour of Apache, or does this look like the behaviour of a certain module?

The server's OS is RHEL 5.8, Apache is 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit was [Apache MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html). This was a frustrating investigation because configuring MultiViews involves no mention of `RewriteRule` or any of the file extensions it will automatically substitute. You have to already know about MultiViews before you can understand that it is causing this behaviour.